# What's the equivalent of @Html.Raw in Postal?

Tags: c#, postal

I'm running [Postal from a service](http://aboutcode.net/postal/outside-aspnet.html).  My @Message has html.  @Html.Raw is not available.  When Postal runs my templated view, I get HtmlEncoded html.  does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried returning it as a `IHtmlString` or `HtmlString`?

Comment: no.  not familiar with IHtmlString.  checking now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our service, we've used:

```
@Raw(StringToBeEncoded)
```

In the html template it will complain it can not be resolved, but at runtime @Raw works fine.  Its part of RazorEngine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@(new System.Web.HtmlString(StringToBeEncoded))
```

which is basically the same as does `HtmlHelper.Raw(StringToBeEncoded)` method under the hood. Moreover, you will not get any error in Visual Studio for the templates.

Comment: Due to the fact Postal uses [RazorEngine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/razorengine) library internally, you can also use `@(new RazorEngine.Text.RawString(StringToBeEncoded))`, as long as you are not going to use the template outside Postal (e.g. to render directly as view in controller methods).

Comment: When sending an email with `Postal.EmailService.Send(email)`, using `HtmlString` will send an encoded version of the HTML, meaning open and closed brackets will be shown. When viewing a preview of the email with `new EmailViewResult(email)`, using `HtmlString` will result in an unencoded string.  

When sending an email with `Postal.EmailService.Send(email)`, using `RawString` will send an unencoded version of the HTML. When viewing a preview of the email with `new EmailViewResult(email)`, using `RawString` will result in an encoded string, meaning open and closed brackets will be shown.